# Factors, hyperreflexivity and derivations

Tags: operator-algebras

Does anyone know about hyperreflexivity of type $II_{\infty}$ factors or derivations of type $II_{1}$ factors?

I mean some relevant paper. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean type $\mathrm{II}_1$ or $\mathrm{II}_\infty$?

Comment: We konw that a lot of $II_{\infty}$ factors are hyperreflexive. Are all of them ?

Comment: Also this problem can be translated to what happens for derivations of $II_{1}$ factors.